# How to show function represent angle of triangle is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $a<b$ real numbers and let $H=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$. Define $u: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $u(z)$ is represent the angle (in radians) between the vector $za$ and the vector $zb$. show that $u$ is harmonic.

What I understand that  $$0<u<\pi$$ but it doesnt't seems to help me. so the only way I think is actually build the function with trigonometry relation and show it by direct calculation. This part is hard for me and I don't know how to actually do it.

Comment: *Hint:* The complex *argument* is the imaginary part of the complex *logarithm.*

Comment: Is this hint means that I need to forget the trigonometry?

Comment: Of course  one *can* prove it with trigonometry. But there is an easier way.

Comment: I think I understood you. since the complex argument of $z$ is bounded this means that  $log(U(z))$ is harmonic? and than is this imply that $u$ is harmonic?

Comment: It's more like $\operatorname{Im}\{\log(\cdots)\} = u(z)$. U is already a log, you are not taking the log of it. You will have to figure out what the $\cdots$ is. If I'm not mistaken, the real range for $u$ should be $(0,\pi)$

Comment: @NinadMunshi ok I think I understood you. can you explain why you argue that the range of $u$ is $(-\pi,\pi)$ how the angle can be negative?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the request. What do $za$ and $zb$ mean? If they are just rescaled copies of $z$, then their angle is zero. Surely I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Those are the vectors connect z to a and z to b correspondly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ be the principal value of the logarithm in $H$, i.e.
$$
 \operatorname{Log} = \log |z| + i \operatorname{Arg}(z) \text{ with } 0 < \operatorname{Arg} < \pi \, .
$$
$\operatorname{Log}$ is holomorphic in $H$, so that its imaginary part $\operatorname{Arg}$ is harmonic in $H$, and so is your function
$$
 u(z) = \operatorname{Arg}(z-b) - \operatorname{Arg}(z-a) \, .
$$